# Find value which is not visible

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageobjects

I have problem I need to compare currency (left top corner) which is set to currency I choose:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <strong>£</strong>
        <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">Currency</span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="EUR">€ Euro</button></li>
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="GBP">£ Pound Sterling</button></li>
        <li><button class="currency-select btn btn-link btn-block" type="button" name="USD">$ US Dollar</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here I choose currency:

```
public void setCurrency(String currencyToSet){
    WebElement currencyVal= driver.findElement(By.name(currencyToSet.toUpperCase()));
    currencyVal.click();    
}
```

I don't know how compare currency I choose with this which is set.

This is how it should look like: [demo.opencart.com](http://demo.opencart.com/)

Comment: The link you posted says the page I requested couldn't be found.

Comment: now its ok, you can check

Comment: And what do you mean by compare currency?

Comment: i have method where i choose curreny for example "EUR" (by name) and click on it. And I have to check that  the current currency is the same I choose in setCurrency method

Comment: So you want it to do what your example is wanting to do? What kind of error are you getting so far? It's really hard to help you with so much information missing and having to dig for it.

Comment: Is below code worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is - you first want to set the currency say '€ Euro' and then you want to check whether '€ Euro' is set or not by verifying Currency Symbol.

So, what you can do is- 
1. Get the Currency Name before selecting it, store it in a variable.
2. Select Currency
3. Finally, extract the Currency Symbol from the Currency Name by splitting it by space. 
4. Now, as you have Currency Symbol, you can easily compare it with what is set.

Here is the C# Code

```
[Test]
    public void Test3()
    {
        string currencyToSet = "EUR";

        IWebElement currencyDropDown = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button[class='btn btn-link dropdown-toggle']"));
        currencyDropDown.Click();

        //Locate the Currency
        IWebElement currencyVal = driver.FindElement(By.Name(currencyToSet.ToUpper()));

        //Before clicking Currency, store Currency Name in a variable.
        string currencyName = currencyVal.Text;

        //Print Currency Name
        Console.WriteLine("Currency Name:" + currencyName);

        //Click on Currency
        currencyVal.Click();

        //Extract Currency Symbol from Currency Name
        string[] spittedCurrencyName = currencyName.Split(' ');
        string currencySymbol = spittedCurrencyName[0];

        //Now you have Currency Symbol. Therefore, you can easily compare it with what is set. 
        Console.WriteLine("Currency Symbole: " + currencySymbol);
    }
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. Hope it will help you.

```
driver.get("http://demo.opencart.com/");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-link dropdown-toggle']")).click();

//WebElement selectCurrency = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='USD']"));
//WebElement selectCurrency = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='GBP']"));
WebElement selectCurrency = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='EUR']"));

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", selectCurrency);

String[] currency = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cart']//span")).getText().split("- ");

String[] c1 = currency[1].split("0.00");

System.out.println(currency[1]);
System.out.println(c1[0]);

if(c1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("$"))
{
    System.out.println("Doller selected");
}
else if(c1[0].equalsIgnoreCase("£"))
{
    System.out.println("Pound");
}
else if(c1[1].equalsIgnoreCase("€"))
{
    System.out.println("Euro");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the code of @amitbobade works gr8 and its easier